# Pause bash script after while read (stdin) loop

Tags: linux, bash, stdin

I am making a script that is taking input via a pipe (stdin), as in (`other_command | my_script`). However, I need to pause the script and wait for the user to press enter, after I have read the whole stdin.

Here is an example-script.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -t 0 ]]; then
  echo "No stdin"
else
  echo "Got stdin"
  while read input; do
    echo $input
  done
fi

echo "Press enter to exit"
read
```

And it works like this;

```
$ echo text | ./script
Got stdin
text
Press enter to exit
$
```

It jumps over my final `read`.

However;

```
$ ./script
No stdin
Press enter to exit
stops here
$
```

How can I get the `read` to work after I have read from stdin? And is there a solution that would work on both Linux and OSX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to read from the user. If stdin is not the user, you have to read from somewhere else. The typical choice is the current terminal (here the terminal connected to stderr, assuming there is one).

```
read -p "Press enter" < "$(tty 0>&2)"
```

By default `tty` finds the name of the tty on stdin, which obviously won't work when stdin is a pipe. Therefore, we redirect to make it look at stderr instead.

Comment: Good points, however, `tty` sais `not a tty` if runned like this. `/dev/ttys006` otherwise. Hence, `read < "/dev/ttys006"` works, but is not feasible.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss a bit of the command somewhere? `"$(tty)"` simply says **execute `tty` and provide the results quoted. `tty` would return something like `/dev/ttys006` (depending on the system/terminal). So `"$(tty)"` should do exactly `"/dev/ttys006"` Execute the following in your terminal to check `( mytty="$(tty)"; echo "tty: $mytty" )`

Comment: `echo "tty" > test; sh test; echo string | sh test` shows one line with `/dev/ttys006` and one with `not a tty`. Happening on both my OSX and Linux test.

Comment: Works like a charm after adding 0>&2 as you edited. :)

Comment: Do you mind writing a quick sum-up of exactly why 0>&2 worked? It will make the answer more complete.